# XPATH: How to select "products" from an xml feed based on part of their "product_name" value

Tags: xpath

I would appreciate your help regarding the following: 
I have a large xml product data feed and want to isolate some products, in order to upload them to my eshop, based on a search keyword in their title.
For example, I have 1.000 products in the xml data feed with the following structure:

```
<product>
 <product_id>18491</product_id>
 <product_name><![CDATA[REFLECTIONS ΔΑΧΤΥΛΙΔΙ]]></product_name>
 <category><![CDATA[ΚΟΣΜΗΜΑΤΑ>ΔΑΧΤΥΛΙΔΙΑ]]></category>
 <shop_url><![CDATA[http://myshop.gr]]></tracking_url>
 <image_url>http://myshop.gr/1R0F001-1000x1000_488x489$.jpg</image_url>
 <price>30</price>
 <program_name>myshop</program_name>
</product>
```

and let's say I want to select ONLY the products that have the keyword "REFLECTIONS" in the "product_name" tag.

Furthermore, can I select a bunch of products by more than one keywords (i.e. products that have the keyword "REFLECTIONS" or "SOMETHING ELSE" or "OTHER VALUE" or.... in their "product_name" tag)?

How do I do that with XPath?

I thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the `contains()` function:

```
/path/to/product[contains(product_name, 'REFLECTIONS')]
```

If you want to have multiple keywords, you can combine them with an `or`:

```
/path/to/product[contains(product_name, 'REFLECTIONS') or contains(product_name, 'SECONDKEYWORD')]
```